# Convert the integer time to yyyy-mm-dd from mysql and read the data from a specific time

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table as DB. The table has three columns and multiple rows. I want to get a the rows which their date is between 2019-2020. However, the date column is integer and I try to use the following code to read it, but I got an error:

```
pd.read_sql("select table.*, date_format(from_unixtime(table.time), '%Y-%m-%d') as
date where date between 'the period I want' from table",db)
```

Here is the table in my database.[image]

Could you please help me with that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from_unixtime()` doesn't return a string... it returns a timestamp that can be compared like any other timestamp.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE le_tbl (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `time` INTEGER,
  `val` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO le_tbl
  (`id`, `time`, `val`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1554012000', '5'),
  ('2', '1554012900', '6'),
  ('3', '1554013800', '7');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT id
     , from_unixtime(time) time_col
     , val
FROM le_tbl
WHERE from_unixtime(time) BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2021-01-01';
```

| id | val | time_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2019-03-31 06:00:00 |
| 2 | 6 | 2019-03-31 06:15:00 |
| 3 | 7 | 2019-03-31 06:30:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s4dr2t3tSTQrcU4iM6yP7j/1)